# How to set bounds on map from my current location to 5 kms away in a radius?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using google map in my android application to show some points on map but i want to restrict the map to a given area for example i want to restrict map boundaries from the user current location to some miles away in a radius.
In google official documentation i find this function:

```
private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-44, 113), new LatLng(-10, 154)); mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(AUSTRALIA, 0));
```

But the problem for me is that how i get the latitude and longitude on a map which are some miles away from user current location. How i set the data in both new LatLng functions.

Comment: SphericalUtil.computeOffset ( http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeOffset-LatLng-double-double- ) is what you want to "...get the latitude and longitude on a map which are some miles...".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty easy way to ballpark a distance by understanding that a degree of latitude is right around 69 miles long.  So if you did something like this:

```
private LatLngBounds AUSTRALIA = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-44.0, 113), new LatLng(-43.5, 113), new LatLng(-44.5, 113));
```

Assuming that the first lat/lon was your current position, you would be creating a bounds with a radius of about 35 miles from your current location.  You can use smaller lat differences if you want a smaller radius, such as -40.0, -40.1, -39.9 use smaller fractions of a degree.  Make sure you only change the latitude coordinate, as the distance between degrees is fixed.  Whereas the distance between degrees of longitude vary depending on the latitude, and it is a much more complex calculation.